What is EPSG:17056?
GeoPDF maps produced in Esri programs by QTopo or nsw.spatial contain EPSG:17056, apparently as the ID/Authority for a UTM CONVERSION. But I can not find EPSG:17056 in the EPSG database, or anywhere else. Can anyone explain EPSG:17056? Here is an example from gdalinfo on one such map (find EPSG:17056 just before CS[Cartesian...):
C:\temp\POTTSVILLE.pdf
Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF
Size is 1984, 1701
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["GDA2020 / MGA zone 56",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GDA2020",
        DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 2020",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",1168]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 56S",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",153,
ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]],
        ID["EPSG",17056]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GeoTransform =
  547812.5023685535, 8.820737271282187, -0.04154086298807071
  6861731.807414656, -0.04124175277187827, -8.818136910349633
Metadata:
  CREATION_DATE=D:20221027175257
  CREATOR=Esri ArcGIS 12.9.3.32739
  DPI=72
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((
548985.517069473 6861166.43868872,
548920.043322868 6847294.03202774,
561185.77072479  6847236.56760398,
561250.999545084 6861109.20634034,
548985.517069473 6861166.43868872))
  TITLE=
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  547812.502, 6861731.807) (153d29'16.64"E, 28d22'11.39"S)
Lower Left  (  547741.841, 6846732.157) (153d29'16.28"E, 28d30'18.81"S)
Upper Right (  565312.845, 6861649.984) (153d39'59.59"E, 28d22'11.32"S)
Lower Right (  565242.184, 6846650.333) (153d40' 0.05"E, 28d30'18.74"S)
Center      (  556527.343, 6854191.070) (153d34'38.14"E, 28d26'15.17"S)
Band 1 Block=1984x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 992x850, 496x425, 248x213
Band 2 Block=1984x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 992x850, 496x425, 248x213
Band 3 Block=1984x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 992x850, 496x425, 248x213


It looks functionally identical to EPSG:7856 - MGA2020 Zone 56.

I know that EPSG:7856 is GDA2020 MGA Zone 56, and the file uses that PROJCRS, but some mapping programs definitely do not see EPSG:17056 as a synonym for EPSG:7856. Nor do EPSG databases list it that way (or any other way). Does anyone know what EPSG:17056 is? Can anyone give an authoritative reference or link?

This is the first time I've seen that EPSG code, the only reference I can find for it is a Stack Overflow question, unsurprisingly having difficulty with projecting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74026802/get-elevation-from-lat-long-of-geotiff-data-in-gdal

Thanks Michael. I am fairly certain (from careful attention to the gdalinfo [ ] structure) that it is a CONVERSION (not PROJCRS) code. It appears at the same place in GDA94 maps from the same sources. So unless multiple map-makers (or multiple Esri products) made the same mistake, it must mean something. This got me thinking. In epsg.io I can find EPSG:17356 and EPSG:17456 for "Map Grid of Australia zone 56" and "Australian Map Grid zone 56" respectively. I guess EPSG:17056 must be a long-forgotten (by everyone except Esri or AU State Government mappers) code for the same conversion.

There are some WKT projections that aren't EPSG codes, Esri has a few SR codes that look like EPSG but aren't, it wouldn't surprise me to find that the code in question is only valid in a specific software package our suite. That being said though the WKT is so close to MGA2020 Zone 56 makes me wonder why they felt a need to hand roll a coordinate reference system. Or perhaps it popped up as a stopgap during the introduction of GDA2020 and was never official.

Since it was present in GDA94 maps, I guess we can eliminate the stopgap for GDA2020 possibility. Indeed, if it was a stopgap at any time, it seems to have been long retained. As for specific Esri products, I have seen it in maps from ArcCatalog 10.3.1.4959 and ArcGIS 12.9.3.32739.

I confirm that at least it is not any EPSG code in any catagory, not even an deprecated one. I would contact the data provider. But the unknown code should not make any issue if the conversion parameters are right. Have you tried to reproject data into some other CRS?

Thanks user30184. Yes, the unknown code is stripped by gdal programs including gdal_translate, gdalwarp and even gdal_edit -a_srs. If  I understand Michael Stimson, he has provided the answer: Most likely 17056 is a "private" code added by Esri and misunderstood by gdalinfo as an EPSG code for the MGA (UTM) Zone 56 (S) CONVERSION. In the unaltered files, the unknown code also confuses some other mapping programs. Brings new meaning to the term "Well Known" Text.

According to: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169193/what-is-the-difference-between-spatialreference-org-catalogs-epsg-esri-and-us
“ESRI has defined its own projections .... Unfortunately, GDAL and QGIS do not reference those projections as ESRI, but as EPSG”.

You have an 8 year old reference. Nowadays Proj and GDAL know quite a many ESRI projections and do not mix them with EPSG. Try for example gdalsrsinfo ESRI:37006.  The problem that you have is that the code ESRI:17056 is not published anywhere. But did you already try for example gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4325 pottsville.pdf potsville_4326.tif? I believe it should work fine.

Thanks user30184. It is good to learn that gdalinfo should now distinguish esri from epsg. But it reports EPSG:17056. I am inclined to trust Michael Stimson's explanation because of his background with esri. But you think he is wrong and nobody has explained EPSG:17056 from gdalinfo? I already noted that gdal_translate, gdalwarp and even gdal_edit -a_srs succeed with such files, but that does not help those who just want to use the published pdfs with one of the mapping programs that are confused by EPSG:17056. Hence my original question.

If you name the ID of the conversion in the WKT into ID["FOO",17056] the GDAL will report it as FOO:17056. Could you name some mapping program that gets confused? Can you point where to download that pdf for testing?

It appeared to be a Proj bug, fixed in https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/4166/files
A related GDAL fix is https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/10133.
Proj calculated the conversion code on the Southern hemisphere as
17000 + zone = 17056
Correct formula is
16100 + zone = 16156
The correct EPSG:16156 code finds an entry from the EPSG registry https://epsg.org/conversion_16156/UTM-zone-56S.html?
The source PDF contains WKT that follows an older, more simple presentation.
PROJCS["GDA2020_MGA_Zone_55",GEOGCS["GDA2020",DATUM["GDA2020",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",147.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

When Proj converted the internal WKT from the PDF file into the most recent WKT2 presentation it added an entry for the the conversion ID. Because of the bug in the formula the value of the ID was wrong. This error should not have an effect for programs that follow the CRS-WKT standard. Because ID EPSG:17056 is not found from the libraries, the conversion parameters are interpreted from the WKT.

Thanks User30184. That explains it! By "It appeared to be" you mean "It is" ... a bug in current versions of GDAL and Proj. I am glad that insistence on getting to the truth about epsg:17056 finally led to identification of the bug, and hopefully a fix in future versions.

The real bug is in Proj versions <= 9.4 and the next Proj version 9.5 will have the fix. For GDAL there is a workaround for the older Proj versions and it will be included in the next GDAL v. 3.9.1. Thus GDAL 3.9.1 will work correctly without a need to upgrade to Proj 9.5 by the same. The codes in WKT2 have been wrong for all southern UTM zones without anybody noticing, which probably proves that the ID is informative.

Identifier is an optional attribute in the "Well-known text representation of
coordinate reference systems" standard https://docs.ogc.org/is/18-010r11/18-010r11.pdf
It acts as a helper metadata for the reader: this part of WKT is also registered under a given authority and ID combination. The coordinate reference system can still be completely resolved by the other attributes without reading information from the authority. In fact the other parameters have a priority if there is a conflict. Excerpt from the standard:

7.3.3 Identifier
Identifier is an optional attribute which references an external
description of the object and which may  be applied to a coordinate
reference system, a coordinate operation or a bound CRS. It may also
be  utilised for components of these objects although this is
recommended only for the following  circumstances:

coordinate operation methods and parameters;
source and target CRSs when embedded within a coordinate transformation or a concatenated  coordinate operation;
source CRS when embedded within a point motion operation;
individual coordinate operations embedded within a concatenated coordinate operation;
base CRS when embedded within a derived CRS (including projected CRS);
source CRS, target CRS and abridged transformation when embedded within a bound CRS;
individual members of a datum ensemble.

Multiple identifiers may be given for any object.  When an identifier
is given for a coordinate reference system, coordinate operation or
bound CRS, it  applies to the whole object including all of its
components. Should any attributes or values given in the cited
identifier be in conflict with attributes or values given  explicitly
in the WKT description, the WKT values shall prevail.

When Proj reads WKT it interprets all the mandatory attributes. It does not matter if the transformation is named as ID["EPSG",17056] but that code cannot be found from the EPSG registry, because ID is skipped anyway.
Of course if user gives GDAL just an ID then GDAL must read the attributes from a database and then the ID must exist and the informatio must be correct. That the ID is skipped when WKT is used can be tested for example this way:
Make GDAL to find the CRS attributes of UTM zone 20 from the local database that contains the EPSG definitions
gdalsrsinfo epsg:32620 -o wkt2 > utm20.prj

Edit the last line to claim that the CRS is UTM zone 30
ID["EPSG",32620]] ->     ID["EPSG",32630]]

Ask projinfo to show how it would transform data into this manipulated CRS and notice that the incorrect ID does not fool it.
projinfo -t epsg:4326 -s @utm20.prj
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

INVERSE(EPSG):16020, Inverse of UTM zone 20N, 0 m, Between 66┬░W and 60┬░W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84┬░N, onshore and offshore.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +inv +proj=utm +zone=20 +ellps=WGS84
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

WKT2:2019 string:
CONVERSION["Inverse of UTM zone 20N",
    METHOD["Inverse of Transverse Mercator",
        ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",9807]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8801]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-63,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8802]],
    PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
        SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
        ID["EPSG",8805]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8806]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8807]],
    ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",16020]]

EDIT:
The EPSG:17056 code is something that GDAL, or probably the Proj library, generates for some yet unknown reason. That code does not exist in the PDF file. The CRS definition that is stored internally into the PDF is much simpler:
PROJCS["GDA2020_MGA_Zone_55",GEOGCS["GDA2020",DATUM["GDA2020",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",147.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]


Thanks user 30184. That is very interesting, though I do not really think that it directly answers the question. (Do you believe that someone invented an epsg:17056 in these maps, or do you think that gdalinfo misinterprets a "private" esri code as an epsg code?)

As mentioned all the geopdf files over several editions from Qtopo (QLD gov spatial service) or nsw.spatial (NSW gov spatial service) give this EPSG:17056 from gdalinfo. That is at least hundreds (probably thousands) of state-government distributed geopdf maps. Both government services use esri products (according to gdalinfo). Why anyone would use a "private" CONVERSION code in such products, and/or why gdalinfo would report it as an epsg code are good questions. But they are not my questions, and I am not qualified to answer.

See my edit. The conversion code does not exist in the PDF file.
